# pagination ul not getting click some times

Tags: jquery, pagination

```js
function paginate_table(row,paginate_div_id, perpage) {
    var items = row;
    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = perpage;
    items.slice(perPage).hide();
    $('#' + paginate_div_id + '').pagination({
        items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: "compact-theme",
        onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
            items.hide()
                    .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });
}
paginate_table($('.dynamicrow'),"searchresult", 10);
$(document).on('click', '#searchresult ul li', function(e) {
console.log(e.target)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row dynamicrow">qwe</div>

<div id="searchresult" class="compact-theme simple-pagination">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#page-1" class="page-link dontprint prev">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#page-1" class="page-link dontprint">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><span class="current dontprint">2</span>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><span class="current dontprint next">Next</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am using the pagination of `simplePagination` like above the way I add is like below.

```
function paginate_table(row,paginate_div_id, perpage) {
    var items = row;
    var numItems = items.length;
    var perPage = perpage;
    items.slice(perPage).hide();
    $('#' + paginate_div_id + '').pagination({
        items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: "compact-theme",
        onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
            items.hide()
                    .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Adding the pagination works ok. The problem is with click the UL number of page and next and prev buttons. sometimes it works sometimes it does.

I am thinking it is because of the selector in the click event.

What is the correct way to target both span and anchor so that they will fire the click event no matter which a click

> I have to click it twice to make it run. the click event like it has to be a span to make it work on anchor it doesnt

`Update`

```
$("#searchresult").on('click','ul li a,span ',function(e){
//        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target)
})
```

Used this one when i click on anchor it is not printing any on console if i click on span it console like this.

`<span class="current dontprint next">Next</span>`

Comment: i have to click it twice to make it run. the click event\

Comment: Have you tried to prevent the default anchor behaviour?

Comment: no wait i will try it

Comment: same result i need to click twice to make it span so it will work

Comment: How did you prevented the default action? Can you please update the question with the code?

Comment: i think i need to select both `span and anchor`? @Ionut

Comment: I don't think there is need for that. Sorry but I can't actually help if I don't see the full working code that shows the problem.. Can you please make a http://jsfiddle.net which shows the problem?

Comment: @Ionut i cant get the link to pagination so it will have error

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent the default behaviour using `.preventDefault()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#searchresult ul li a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with simple click event -

```
$('#searchresult ul li').click(function() {
  //your function
});
```

If you are loading **#searchresult** content from ajax you can try below -

```
$('body').on('click', '#searchresult ul li', function() {
  //your function
});
```